# How to parse and split a dynamic string in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, parsing, split

I have been learning VB.net organically on the job for a couple months now. I am not familiar with basic programming terminology and jargon, and this likely hinders me in searching for an answer. Nonetheless, I will try my best to search for an answer on my own. Here's my question:

Let's say I have a string that dynamically changes. How do I split and parse the string to get my numbers regardless of the string format and how many numbers there are? I have been reading about the Regex.Match function which seems to be what I need. Here are some examples of strings I am running into, and the ideal outputs.

---

Example 1:

"25% initial deposit, 60% equipment deposit, 15% due upon completion"

> 25

> 60

> 15

---

Example 2:

"Payment Schedule: 0.75, 0.25"

> 0.75

> 0.25

---

Example 3:

"12.5% due upon signing contract, 25-25-25 monthly deposits, 12.5% due upon completion"

> 12.5

> 25

> 25

> 25

> 12.5

Comment: `Regex.Matches` + e.g., `\d+[.,]*\d+%*`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Jimi, can you explain your reply? Perhaps you can provide an example?